# Php Json Decode - Display value of second level items

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, api

I'm trying to decode JSON format
My API Endpoint is https://api.reliableserver.host/api/landings

And this is the output

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "primary_balance": "$4,184.37",
            "primary_currency": "USD",
            "secondary_balance": "¥0",
            "secondary_currency": "JPY",
            "tertiary_balance": "฿0.00",
            "tertiary_currency": "THB",
            "first_language": "ไทย",
            "second_language": "English",
            "footer_text": "a",
            "created_at": "2020-10-26T07:45:49.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-10-28T05:31:04.000000Z",
            "deleted_at": null
        }
    ],
    "message": "Landings retrieved successfully"
}
```

I need to echo individual values, for example: Primary Balance: $4,184.37

I tried using this:

```php
$url = "https://api.reliableserver.host/api/landings";
    
$obj = json_decode($url);
    
echo $obj>primary_balance;
```

But it didnt work, kindly guide me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: you need to fetch the values coming from that url first, then you decode the results. you could use `file_get_contents` or implement the `cURL` lib in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way :

```
$url = '{"success": true,"data": [{"id": 1,"primary_balance": "$4,184.37","primary_currency": "USD","secondary_balance": "¥0","secondary_currency": "JPY","tertiary_balance": "฿0.00","tertiary_currency": "THB","first_language": "ไทย","second_language": "English","footer_text": "a","created_at": "2020-10-26T07:45:49.000000Z","updated_at": "2020-10-28T05:31:04.000000Z","deleted_at": null}],"message": "Landings retrieved successfully"}';
$obj = json_decode($url, true);
echo $obj['data'][0]['primary_balance'];
// output $4,184.37
```

Above code tested **[here](https://rextester.com/YMLDJ78385)**

You need [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) method to get the JSON data from your given URL.

```
$url = "https://api.reliableserver.host/api/landings";
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
echo $obj['data'][0]['primary_balance'];
// output $4,184.37
```

Comment: thanks @sta I did not know about rextester until now

Comment: this is great, it worked perfectly. I used it for the landing page.

Comment: One question, I have another similar endpoint but with multiple data. I implemented your method and it worked to display the first chunk of data, but how do i go about doing a for each so i can display all the data and not just the first one. this is the endpoint in questions: https://api.reliableserver.host/api/recent_activities

Comment: @ElB. Its really hard to tell you without see the code, I suggest you to ask a new question, so that we can help you :)

Comment: Please check it here, I asked my friend at the office to post instead, cz my account is still new. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64567941/php-json-decode-working-for-first-item-only-trying-to-implement-for-each

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are not calling that api anywhere. If it is an open endpoint (without auth or headers, you can do [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or I suggest you to use [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php).
Also, you need to check on response data structure, it has a 'data' key which is an array. so you need to use [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate on the 'data' key.

I have given a sample answer that should work if there is only 1 item in data.

```
    $url = "https://api.reliableserver.host/api/landings";
    $resp = file_get_contents($url);
    $obj= json_decode($resp);// will return in object form
    echo $obj->data[0]->primary_balance;
```

or

```
$url = "https://api.reliableserver.host/api/landings";
$resp = file_get_contents($url);
$obj= json_decode($resp, true); // will return in array form
echo $obj['data'][0]['primary_balance'];
```

[json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: what if i have more than one item in my data, how do i go about doing for each? this si the endpoint in questions https://api.reliableserver.host/api/recent_activities