# PHP 'json_decode' Working for First Item Only

Tags: php, json, api, loops, foreach

I'm decoding JSON format, my API Endpoint is https://api.reliableserver.host/api/recent_activities (No Auth)

I've already managed to display the values of the first item like this:

```
<?php
$url2 = "https://api.reliableserver.host/api/recent_activities";
$obj2 = json_decode(file_get_contents($url2), true);
?>

<tr class="css-xlbdcw">

    <td style="width: unset; max-width: unset; padding: 5px 20px; text-align: left;">
        <div class="vx_text-body-md" style="color: rgb(44, 46, 47); padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px;">
            <div role="button">
                <?php echo $obj2['data'][0]['activity_date']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>

    <td style="width: unset; max-width: unset; padding: 5px 20px; text-align: left;">
    <div data-testid="verticalList">
        <a tabindex="0" href="/activity/payment/87J62844XL761054H"><?php echo $obj2['data'][0]['activity_title']; ?></a>
        <div style="color: rgb(44, 46, 47); font-size: 11px;"><?php echo $obj2['data'][0]['activity_status']; ?></div>
    </div>
    </td>

    <td style="width: unset; max-width: unset; padding: 5px 20px; text-align: right;">
        <div class="vx_text-body-md" style="color: rgb(44, 46, 47); padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px;">
            <div role="button"><?php echo $obj2['data'][0]['activity_amount']; ?></div>
        </div>
    </td>

</tr>
```

This is working for the first item, how do i make it go through each item using `foreach` - I tried but couldn't get it working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over `$obj2['data']`:

```
$url2 = "https://api.reliableserver.host/api/recent_activities";
$obj2 = json_decode(file_get_contents($url2), true);

foreach ($obj2['data'] as $item) {?>
<tr class="css-xlbdcw">

    <td style="width: unset; max-width: unset; padding: 5px 20px; text-align: left;">
        <div class="vx_text-body-md" style="color: rgb(44, 46, 47); padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px;">
            <div role="button">
                <?php echo $item['activity_date']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>

    <td style="width: unset; max-width: unset; padding: 5px 20px; text-align: left;">
        <div data-testid="verticalList">
            <a tabindex="0" href="/activity/payment/87J62844XL761054H"><?php echo $item['activity_title']; ?></a>
            <div style="color: rgb(44, 46, 47); font-size: 11px;"><?php echo $item['activity_status']; ?></div>
        </div>
    </td>

    <td style="width: unset; max-width: unset; padding: 5px 20px; text-align: right;">
        <div class="vx_text-body-md" style="color: rgb(44, 46, 47); padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px;">
            <div role="button"><?php echo $item['activity_amount']; ?></div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
```

Comment: superb, its working - ill accept the answer in 9 minutes as the system won't allow me now

Comment: Ths answer is more accurate than the other one

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to allow yourself flexibility in rendering items, you could use a filter array (`$filter`), as follows:

```
<?php
$response = file_get_contents('https://api.reliableserver.host/api/recent_activities');
$response = json_decode($response, true);
$filter = ['id', 'activity_amount']; // select which items to show
foreach ($response['data'] as $record) {
    echo '<tr class="css-xlbdcw">'; // open row
    foreach ($record as $key => $item) {
        if (in_array($key, $filter)) { // show filtered items only
            echo <<<HEREDOC
    <td style="width: unset; max-width: unset; padding: 5px 20px; text-align: left;">
        <div class="vx_text-body-md" style="color: rgb(44, 46, 47); padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px;">
            <div role="button">
                $item
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
HEREDOC;
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>'; // close row
}
```

We use [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) as it allows us to elegantly render HTML with variable(s) (e.g. `$item`) injected.